# Rename menu items for All except super admin

Tags: menus, wp-admin

I can rename wp-admin menu items But How Can I active it for all users except Super Admin ?

```
add_filter('gettext', 'rename_admin_menu_items');
add_filter('ngettext', 'rename_admin_menu_items');
function rename_admin_menu_items( $menu ) {
$menu = str_ireplace( 'Dashboard', 'Home', $menu );
return $menu;
}
```

Comment: Which hook are you using?

Comment: And where/when does that function run/gets executed?

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong ,I fixed the code.

Comment: ***Never!***, ***ever*** hook into `gettext`, `ngettext` and similar without instantly removing the attached callbacks! Those filters trigger hundreds of times on each request and can pull your site down to its knees. Seriously. Don't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * Changes Label of Admin Menu items
 * @global array $menu
 * @global array $submenu
*/
function change_post_menu_label() {
   global $menu;
   global $submenu;
   $menu[2][0] = 'Home'; 
   $menu[5][0] = 'Articles';
   $submenu['edit.php'][5][0] = "All Articles";
   //    var_dump($submenu);
   //    var_dump($menu);
    echo '';
  }
  if(!is_super_admin()){
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'change_post_menu_label' );
  }
```

You can print the array

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($menu);
echo "</pre>"; //remove this code after, it is just used to check the index of element in Menu to rename it.
```

and see elements index to change name for whatever item you'would like to rename. Like in above function I'm renaming the "Posts" in menu to "Articles".

To rename the child of Menu item use

```
$submenu
```

array. For renaming Dashboard to "Home"

```
  $menu[2][0] = 'Home';
```

add this line to previous function, confirm the index "2" in $menu array for Dashboard.

Comment: thanks bro...how can i rename the "Dashboard" menu to "Home"?

Comment: I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the user role. Setup a condition like this:

```
if(current_user_can("manage_network")) add_action("rename_admin_menu_items","your-hook");
```

References:
[User roles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

Comment: doesn't work, How should the entire code?